# Nested JSON stream using NewEncoder

Tags: go

I am wondering whether it is possible to stream JSON and include other (sibling) keys besides the stream itself? I would like to include some extra data about the generated file. Something like the following:

```
{
    "info": {
        "department": "a",
        "id": "1",
    },
    "members": [
        { "name": "a", "age": "1" },
        { "name": "b", "age": "2" },
        { "name": "c", "age": "3" },
        ...stream
    ]
}
```

Currently, I stream JSON to a flat file like so:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
)

type Member struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

func main() {
    enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)

    letters := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}

    for i, letter := range letters {
        key := Member{letter, i}

        var err = enc.Encode(&key)
        if err != nil {
            // handle err
        }
    }
}
```

But as indicated above I would like to add another key such as "info" and contain the stream in a key such as "members"

I can think of a solution to the problem, which would store them as separate files in a directory, e.g.

```
directory
├─ members.json
└─ info.json
```

But could other (sibling) keys be added or am I limited to a flat file?

Comment: @mkopriva I updated it. It was supposed to be an example of the structure that I am after. I realize the code works, but I am not writing to `os.Stdout` in my implementation, but to a file. My question is whether a streamed .json file can be created with the example hierarchy displayed above. As it stands, I am only able to generate a flat file containing the contents of  the `members` key. Perhaps I am trying to do something that is not idiomatic at all?

Comment: `os.Stdout` or `os.File`, to the encoder it doesn't matter, it's all `io.Writer`. What you can do is to write to the `io.Writer` the enclosing braces and the `"info": ` key, then using the encoder write the info object, then again manually writing `, "members": [ `to the `io.Writer` and back to the encoder writing the stream of members + a comma after each but the last, and finally closing it with `]}`.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar is possible, but it's not especially simple.  I have done something similar in one of my open-source projects in a PR that I have not yet merged. But you can see my example [here](https://github.com/go-kivik/couchdb/pull/59/files#diff-7a117cbfd5485ed35efcbb2995c37aa0R306).

The interface I expose is to take in an `io.ReadCloser` and return a (possibly manipulated) `io.ReadCloser`.  Internally, it uses a `json.Decoder` to parse the JSON, possibly adding new data to the stream.  I'm not sure how a `json.Encoder` would fit into this (as asked in your question).

Producing a complete working example for you would be a pretty big task for an SO answer, but I hope the link I provided can point you in the right direction.

This is a case where good unit tests, and a TDD approach, would be well advised!